# How to start Vert.x server from IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, vert.x

How do I start a simple Vert.x server from inside IntelliJ IDEA?

My `build.gradle` is as below:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

version = '3.0.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.vertx:vertx-core:3.0.0'
}
```

My Vertx-server, `MyVertex.java` is as below:

```
package com.example;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Future;

public class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> fut) {
        vertx.createHttpServer()
                .requestHandler(r -> r.response().end("<h1>Hello</h1>"))
                .listen(8081);
    }
}
```

And my IntelliJ run configuration is as below, with `io.vertx.core.Starter`as main class:
[image]

But when I run it with my run configuration I get this error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class run
```

Is the VM option (in Run configuration) `run` something I need to install and add to my path or how do I get started with Vert.x-server development?

Comment: shouldn't in `VM Options` be just your class name?

Comment: @injecteer: then I get this error message: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.MyVerticle`

Comment: On this page it is "run <class>" as VM Option https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/gradle-verticles/gradle-verticle

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I'm using vertx 3.2.1 and it's complaining about `io.vertx.core.Starter`. It's deprecated now. So, one should use `io.vertx.core.Launcher`.

This is an example of launching via intellij with the option of specifying a config JSON file:

- Main Class: `io.vertx.core.Launcher`
- VM Options: `<up to you, or leave blank>`
- Program Arguments: `run com.app.verticle.MyVerticle -conf /path/to/my_config.json`

When using a logging framework it will be added in VM Options as below.

**Log4j with either log4j or slf4j delgate:**

```
-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.vertx.core.logging.Log4jLogDelegateFactory -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.xml

-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.vertx.core.logging.SLF4JLogDelegateFactory -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.xml
```

**Logback:**

```
-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.vertx.core.logging.SLF4JLogDelegateFactory -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml
```

Comment: I tried -conf /path/my_config.json and -conf \path\my_config.json but didn't work. I'm using windows. What could be the problem?

Comment: @MoA - what happens when you specify the complete path to conf? Example: 

    -conf c:/apps/conf/my_config.json ...

Answer (score 32):

Simply add this to your `MyVerticle` (or a separate class):

```
import io.vertx.core.Launcher;
...
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Launcher.executeCommand("run", MyVerticle.class.getName());
}
```

Then simply `Ctrl+Shift+F10` to run it and IntelliJ will automatically create the `Run Configuration`.

Comment: This is more useful because in case you want to pass a promise to your verticle's start method

Answer (score 8):

Ah, my mistake:

`run com.example.MyVerticle` should be the value of **Program arguments:** and not as *VM options* in the IntelliJ IDEA Run configuration.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add a main and use deployVerticle() and then from there in IntelliJ you can Run or Debug it easily.
With deployVerticle, you can pass a new instance of your main/bootstrap verticle or you can pass yourMainVerticle.class

```
public class VertxVerticleMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        vertx.deployVerticle(new MyVerticle());
       //vertx.deployVerticle(MyVerticle.class);

    }
}
```