# Vertx2: org.vertx.java.platform.impl.cli.Starter

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, vert.x

I'm writing a "Hello-World" application in Vertx2. 
I have the following dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-platform</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-beta1</version>
        </dependency>
```

and run it as IntelliJ application with the following configuration:
[image]

I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>
> org.vertx.java.core.impl.VertxInternal.getOrAssignContext()Lorg/vertx/java/core/impl/DefaultContext;

Do you know what is the problem here?

Edit:
This project is for Vertx version 2 (not version 3). This is why the solution in this [IntelliJ and Vertx: How to run org.vertx.java.deploy.impl.cli.Starter ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283326/intellij-and-vertx-how-to-run-org-vertx-java-deploy-impl-cli-starter) doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Why do you use so old version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ and Vertx: How to run org.vertx.java.deploy.impl.cli.Starter ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283326/intellij-and-vertx-how-to-run-org-vertx-java-deploy-impl-cli-starter)

Comment: Why did you post the same question twice?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. I just changed the version numbers for vertx-core and vertx-platform, and now it works.

The new dependencies in pom.xml are:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1RC3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-platform</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
```