# Vert.x project how to build a jar containing all other verticles

Tags: java, maven, vert.x

I would like your help here as i am writing my first vert.x Project in java. I am using maven. I have 4 different verticle and one of the is my Main verticle (MainVerticle.java). I am using a programatical deployment and my MainVerticle.java contains the deployment of my 3 other verticles.
I am having hard tine to run my MainVerticle on command line.
I did some search at i have found it is possible to run a jar file. The problem I have is that as it is a vert.x project my jar that i built by using intellij does not contain the other 3 verticles.
I always use my ide to create a jar for all my java project but I do not know why I cannot get the 3 other verticles in my jar in order to run my MainVeeticle with the 3 others.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to refer to either of these project setup:

- https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-maven-starter
- https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/maven-simplest

And there is also this blogpost that may helps you

- https://vertx.io/blog/my-first-vert-x-3-application/

Answer (score 0):

You can run them using intelliJ, edit your run configurations as follows:

- Main Class: `io.vertx.core.Launcher`
- VM Options: `<up to you, or leave blank>`
- Program Arguments: `run com.main.MainVerticle`

In the Program Arguments specify the correct package that contains your MainVerticle.java verticle

If you are using a json config file you can do the following:

Program Arguments: `run com.main.MainVerticle -conf /path/to/my_config.json`

Source:
[How to start Vert.x server from IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205477/how-to-start-vert-x-server-from-intellij-idea)