# How can I start a Vert.x Verticle in debug mode in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, vert.x, vertx-verticle

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205477/how-to-start-vert-x-server-from-intellij-idea), but not quite a duplicate (I think).

I have a Vert.x Verticle, which I run as described in the answer to the above question (i.e. by executing `io.vertx.core.Launcher` with relevant arguments, but I'm trying to start the same thing in debug mode.

Elsewhere in answers to the above question, I've seen people recommending adding a `main()` method to a Verticle and executing that in either run or debug mode, but I'd rather not add redundant code purely for this purpose.

The only option I can think of would be to start the Verticle as I am doing, but using the VM arguments to have it wait for a debugger, and then start a remote debug configuration in IntelliJ. That feels clumsy though; is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `main()` method.

That's the minimal Verticle you need:

```
public class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Verticle started");
    }
}
```

And that's how it should be launched:
[image]

After you've done that, just put a debug point in your verticle and start your application in debug mode.