# Is there any way to debug vertx in vscode?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vert.x

How do I debug vertx code in VScode ?
I tried to find any plugin for vertx debug in marketplace. i didn't found that.
Do you know? please help me~!!
Thank you.

Comment: If there is no debug adapter for this language you have to write it yourself in an extension

Comment: I don't know if this would be suitable, but you could use IntelliJ instead of VSCode. It's much easier to use to debug Java code (assuming that's the variant of Vert.x you're using).

Comment: If you can debug the language you are using in VS Code, so you can debug vert.x as well, vert.x is just a framework You may check [debugging in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging).

Answer (score 0):

This [answer from another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44716047/887836) works like a charm.

If you have a main verticle you want to run. Add the code below to make one of you classes an executable main class.

to the imports section:

```
import io.vertx.core.Launcher;
```

in the main verticle add a static method:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Launcher.executeCommand("run", MyVerticle.class.getName());
}
```